# Error handling: extracting context of error

Tags: go

I have a function which return `error`:

```
func foo(i int) error {
    err := errors.New("error here")

    if i == 1 {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "one")
    }

    if i == 2 {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "two")  
    }

    return nil
}
```

I want to handle an error in the calling function, but to do it, I need to know the context of error. Something like this:

```
err := foo(i) 

switch err.getContext() {
  case "foo":
  case "bar":
}
```

I have found [causer](https://godoc.org/github.com/pkg/errors) interface, but I don't know how to use it here.

Or do I need to create the different types (`struct`) for each type of error here ?

Comment: You can use the [`errors.Is`](https://golang.org/pkg/errors/#Is) function to check the error type or [`errors.Unwrap`](https://golang.org/pkg/errors/#Unwrap) to access its inner error.

Comment: What is the "context of error"? There is no such thing in Go,

Comment: @Volker, i used this work because it was used in the documentation - `the errors.Wrap function returns a new error that adds context to the original error` - I have post the link in the question.

Comment: This is **informal** language. The "context" mentioned is the additional text and there is _no_ (reliable way) to get it. (Nitpick: adding the stacktrace is also "context" here and you can get the stacktrace, but that is not what you are taking about here). And this is good: This "context" is for human consumption. If you need to distinguish errors: Use different types or a type with exposes this distinction criteria.

Comment: @Volker, thanks. Can you please look at this code https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/229555/error-handling-in-go. I put it in the Code Review, becasue it look like the better place for this question. Do you mean this approach when you were talking about different types?